# Converting a list of values to between -1 and 1

Tags: excel, statistics, formula

I have a questionnaire with answers in a number of different formats. I want the range to be between -1 and 1. However, not all ranges include negative numbers.

I need to create an excel formula to convert the value to the following dependent upon the range.

```
+---+--------+
| A |To this | 
+---+--------+
|-3 |  -1    |
|-2 | -0.66  |
|-1 | -0.33  |
| 0 |   0    |
| 1 |   1    |
+---+--------+
```

Or

```
+---+--------+
| A |To this | 
+---+--------+
| 0 |   0    |
| 1 |  0.25  |
| 2 |  0.5   |
| 3 |  0.75  |
| 4 |   1    |
+---+--------+
```

Or

```
+---+--------+
| A |To this | 
+---+--------+
| 1 |  0.2   |
| 2 |  0.4   |
| 3 |  0.6   |
| 4 |  0.8   |
| 5 |   1    |
+---+--------+
```

Or

```
+---+--------+
| A |To this | 
+---+--------+
|-2 |  -1    |
|-1 |  -0.5  |
| 0 |   0    |
| 1 |  0.5   |
| 2 |   1    |
+---+--------+
```

etc.

Comment: Won't that create weird skew in your data if the `-∞,0` range and the `0,∞` ranges are being re-scaled using different factors?

Comment: Yeah, I think it will. But as the scores they are given are completely arbitrary it feels like the best way. I did normalise the data between 0 and 1 but this approach allows the negative values to work against the overall score.

Comment: Why would `-1` correspond to `-0.33` and not `-0.5` like in the 2nd example.  The span is still `4` and `-1` is still `2` away from both the MIN and MAX.  Same with 0 and -2

Comment: Because there are 3 negative values in the first example - this is then split 3 ways. There are 4 positive values in the second example - this is therefore divided to 4 equal parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula should do the trick:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A1<=0,-1*A1/(MIN(A:A)+MIN(0,MAX(A:A))),A1/(MAX(A:A))),0)
```

This produces this example output when autofilled down:

```
-3  -1
-2  -0.666666667
-1  -0.333333333
 0   0
 1   0.2
 2   0.4
 3   0.6
 4   0.8
 5   1
```

Note: this includes `0` for both sets of `-1,0` and `0,1`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for all different ranges. I will update the question to include more examples.

Comment: @hc91 Fixed.  The positive case didn't need a min check since the min should always be 0

Comment: If the minimum value of the range is zero, as in example two of the OP, you get a #DIV/0! error. I fixed that by wrapping the formula with IFERROR(...,0)

Answer (score 0):

If the range of input numbers is finite, even with negative numbers, you can use the general range mapping formula as below.

If the range of input numbers is [X1:X2] and the range of output numbers is [Y1:Y2] (in your case [-1:+1]) then number x is mapped to number y in the output range with the following formula:

**y = (x - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1) + Y1**

when **X2-X1 != 0**